# In Emacs Calc, how do I find the distance between two points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2)?

Tags: calc

I'm trying to calculate the euclidean distance between two points `(x1,y1)` and `(x2,y2)` which is

```
sqrt( (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 )
```

Is there a way to calculate this easily with Emacs calc?

(I looked in the Info pages, but was not able to tell if there a way to do this easily. I can use `f h` to compute the hypotenuse, but I can't figure out how to use that with points, or if Emacs has any first class notion of a point)

Comment: You can enter points as complex.  abs((3,4))=>5 or abs(3+4i)=>5. For your example abs((x2,y2)-(x1,y1))=sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2)

Comment: you can also enter points as array. abs([x2, y2] - [x1, y1])=>hypot(x2 - x1, y2 - y1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can represent points with complex numbers or vectors.
The calc-abs (A) function returns the absolute value of a complex number or the Euclidean norm of a vector.
For instance this is the trail trace which results from the calculus of the distance from [7 -2] to [4 2]

```
Emacs Calculator Trail
alg' [7, -2]
alg' [4, 2]
   - [-3, 4]
 abs 5
```

Comment: You should expand your answer to include all of the details in your comments: that would make it much more useful.

Comment: The main point is that you can use the abs function for complex numbers or for vectors. I can't imagine that calculate a difference could create any difficulties. Points can be represented either with complex numbers or vectors, depending on the context.

Comment: Thanks! You may be right, but IME, the more detailed the answer, the more helpful it is (not only for the OP, but also for future visitors).